# Getting directory portion of a list of source files in a for loop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following gnu make script:

```
for hdrfile in $(_PUBLIC_HEADERS) ; do \
    echo $(dir $$hdrfile) ; \
done
```

The `_PUBLIC_HEADERS` variable has a list of relative paths, like so:

```
./subdir/myheader1.h
./subdir/myheader2.h
```

The output I get from the for loop above is:

```
./
./
```

I expect to see:

```
./subdir/
./subdir/
```

What am I doing wrong? Note that if I change the code to:

```
echo $(dir ./subdir/myheader1.h)
```

it works in this case. I think maybe it has something to do with the for loop but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing `make` variables (or functions) with shell variables when executing the `for`-loop. Note that `$(dir ...)` is a `make` construct that gets expanded by `make` before the command is executed by the shell. However, you want the shell to execute that command inside the loop.

What you could do is replace `$(dir)` with the corresponding command `dirname` which gets executed by the shell. So it becomes:

```
for hdrfile in $(_PUBLIC_HEADERS) ; do \
    dirname $$hdrfile ; \
done
```

This should give the desired result.

Comment: Well I really need to add that directory path to another path, like so: `$(PUBLISH_ROOT)/include/$(MODULE)/$(dir $$hdrfile)`. I don't know how to do this with your suggestion.

Comment: OK, but that is a different question :-). You can use the construction `$(addprefix  $(PUBLISH_ROOT)/include/$(MODULE)/,$(dir $(_PUBLIC_HEADERS)))`, which yields the directorynames you are looking for. However, the result will contain a list of directorynames, one for each entry in `$(_PUBLIC_HEADERS)`. Is that what you want?